# Prepopulate Content Type Args when going to /admin/content in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I created a Drupal site. The admins who will be using the site for content management have no Drupal knowledge and I have been tasked with making this as easy as possible for them. I'm creating an admin control panel and I want a quick link that takes them to the admin content page, but with the "content type" prefilled. For example, for content I have pages, events, resources, and testimonials. I want to provide them with a quick link for editing content type EVENTS only. So it would go directly to admin/content with the type filter set to "events". The URL does not currently add args or anything like that.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this- just use this module: [Drupal admin views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) which supports a REGULAR VIEW for admin/content. The View is set to use ajax though- just remove this option and save it and call /admin/content then. There you will see the resulting filters in the URL (you can even set their keys to a value you like inside the view). Set back to use ajax (if you like) and use the keys in the URL for type it's simple just call /admin/content?type=YOURTYPE